# what is standard notation of JSON keys

Tags: javascript, json

I think standard notation for javascript properties is camelCase (most of frameworks in javascript use camelCase), so JSON keys must be camelCase (according to javascript object notation), also I've seen WIKIPEDIA and W3SCHOOLS documentation about JSON, all sample wrote in camelCase, but when see API documentation of Twitter, Facebook, Instagram and ... all API key wrote in underscore separated notation.

What is standard notation of JSON?

```
{
    "firstName" : "behrooz"
}
```

or

```
{
    "first_name" : "behrooz"
}
```

Comment: Take your pick.  I interoperate with C#/.NET a lot, so most of mine are of the form `"FirstName"`.

Answer (score 2):

JSON defines no convention for the choice of property names. There is no standard for this.

Comment: Upvoted on the basis that this is the only reasonable answer, though the Q ought to be closed as opinion based.

Comment: Hmm that sounds rather contradictory.  If this is the only reasonable answer, the Q is by definition not opinion based... I'm now in a quandary :)

Comment: and which one is best practice? @Quentin

Comment: @Behrooz — That's a matter of opinion (and off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet on Googles intepretation on JSON naming conventions...

Choose meaningful property names.
Property names must conform to the following guidelines:

- Property names should be meaningful names with defined semantics.
- Property names must be camel-cased, ascii strings. The first
- character must be a letter, an underscore (_) or a dollar sign ($).
- Subsequent characters can be a letter, a digit, an underscore, or a
  dollar sign. Reserved JavaScript keywords should be avoided (A list
  of reserved JavaScript keywords can be found below).

These guidelines mirror the guidelines for naming JavaScript identifiers. This allows JavaScript clients to access properties using dot notation. (for example, result.thisIsAnInstanceVariable). Here's an example of an object with one property:

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Updated to preserve link content information.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll find JSON keys to be camel cased. This is of course entirely up to the developer, and many APIs use underscores. But the mainstream solution is `propertyName`.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to [JSON API.org](http://jsonapi.org/)

It should be,

```
 {
   "first-name": "John"
 }
```

Comment: That's JSON API, which is a separate spec to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Check JSON standarts specification here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627

As you  can see there is not standart format vor objects key.

Comment: Interesting that in that RFC the examples have different conventions being used